# select case with order by in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am running following query to find the best winning streak for user.

```
$sql="select sub.user_id as user_id,max(sub.streak) as streak,max(sub.units) as units
                from
                  (
                select 
                case when @x is null then @x:=user_id end,
                case 
                when awarded_unit>0 and @x=user_id then @y:=@y+1 
                when awarded_unit<0 and @x=user_id then @y:=0 
                when awarded_unit>0 and @x<>user_id then @y:=1
                when awarded_unit<0 and @x<>user_id then @y:=0
                end as streak,
                case 
                when awarded_unit>0 and @x=user_id then @z:=@z+awarded_unit 
                when awarded_unit<0 and @x=user_id then @z:=0 
                when awarded_unit>0 and @x<>user_id then @z:=awarded_unit 
                when awarded_unit<0 and @x<>user_id then @z:=0
                end as units,
                @x:=user_id as user_id,
                awarded_unit
                from $select_user_events_fights as u,$events as e,$event_fight_table as ef,$post_meta as pm where e.ID=ef.event_id
                and ef.event_fight_id=u.event_fight_id and  e.post_type='bt_events' and pm.post_id = e.ID and  e.post_status ='publish' and pm.meta_key='_event_dt_time' and u.`awarded_unit`!=0 and u.season_id=$season_id and u.user_id=".$user->ID."

                order by pm.meta_value desc,ef.fight_order desc
                  ) as sub
                group by sub.user_id";


            mysql_query("set @y=0;");
            mysql_query("set @x=null;");
            mysql_query("set @z=0;");
```

It works fine if I put order by u.primary_key. But I wants events to be sorted by date and fight order . it gives wrong result in this case.

I had checked inner query with order by statement.

for order by statement(`"order by pm.meta_value desc,ef.fight_order desc"`) ,it is sorting results
after calculating the best streak so it is giving wrong result.

Kindly explain how to get correct answer and what I am missing here.Thanks

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the 
community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/q0gwD). See
 the [red box](http://goo.gl/OWwr2)? Instead you should learn about [prepared
 statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://goo.gl/TD3xh) or [MySQLi](http://in3.php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you.
 If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/b2ATO).
 Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/J5jAo)

Comment: ok, I will learn PDO, but it was related to some old code , I developed. Thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the ORDER BY in a subquery, and then perform the streak detection in an outer query that processes that.

Try this (untested -- if you want me to test, supply some data in a sqlfiddle):

```
      $sql="select sub.user_id as user_id,max(sub.streak) as streak,max(sub.units) as units
            from
              (
            select 
            case when @x is null then @x:=user_id end,
            case 
            when awarded_unit>0 and @x=user_id then @y:=@y+1 
            when awarded_unit<0 and @x=user_id then @y:=0 
            when awarded_unit>0 and @x<>user_id then @y:=1
            when awarded_unit<0 and @x<>user_id then @y:=0
            end as streak,
            case 
            when awarded_unit>0 and @x=user_id then @z:=@z+awarded_unit 
            when awarded_unit<0 and @x=user_id then @z:=0 
            when awarded_unit>0 and @x<>user_id then @z:=awarded_unit 
            when awarded_unit<0 and @x<>user_id then @z:=0
            end as units,
            @x:=user_id as user_id,
            awarded_unit
            from (select user_id, awarded_unit
                  from $select_user_events_fights as u,$events as e,$event_fight_table as ef,$post_meta as pm where e.ID=ef.event_id
            and ef.event_fight_id=u.event_fight_id and  e.post_type='bt_events' and pm.post_id = e.ID and  e.post_status ='publish' and pm.meta_key='_event_dt_time' and u.`awarded_unit`!=0 and u.season_id=$season_id and u.user_id=".$user->ID."

                  order by pm.meta_value desc,ef.fight_order desc) as subsub
            ) as sub
            group by sub.user_id";
```

Comment: thanks Barmar, it worked.Yes, you are very correct that I needs to get first sorted result. Thanks a lot :)